# How to auth google API c# on Centos with Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I need to run a c# program that I created on my VPS that runs Linux (Centos 7). The program uses Youtube C# Api (more specifically uses [this base](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/UploadVideo.cs) for video upload).

The first time I ran the code on my PC, the browser opened and I had to allow the access to my account. The problem is: on centos there is no browser, only a terminal. How can I auth the program into my account without a browser?

```
Error: Failed to launch browser with 
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=blablablablabablablablablaba" for authorization. 
See inner exception for details.
```

Is it possible to "bypass" this? How?

Btw, I'm a linux begginner.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Google's API client for .NET?

https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client

> The Google API client library for .NET enables access to Google APIs
>   such as Drive, YouTube, Calendar, Storage and Analytics. The library
>   supports OAuth2.0 authentication. Strongly-typed per-API libraries are
>   generated using Google's Discovery API.

Comment: I'm using exactly those. I'm using this [base](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/UploadVideo.cs) in case you didn't see.

Comment: Check section "Installed applications" in sample docs:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: I just managed to pull it out another way arround. I'm editing the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the authentication on my PC that has a browser, went to the **%appdata%/Roaming/Google.Apis.Auth** and found the token file there.

Then I searched for %appdata% equivalent on Centos Linux (in my case was .config/Google.Apis.Auth/). Pasted the Token file from my PC there. And boom, it's working.